# How to end this loop in Java (Updated Quest.)

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I am a beginner programmer learning java for the first time.  I cant figure out how to make the program repeat itself until the user enters 0.
here is the problem:
The application should allow the user to input as many model numbers as needed. Use 0 as a sentinel to end user input.

**Enter the car's model number or 0 to quit: 195
Your car is defective. It must be repaired.
Enter the car's model number or 0 to quit: 119
Your car is defective. It must be repaired.
Enter the car's model number or 0 to quit: 0**

```
 public class CarRecall
{
// Main method
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int model; //model number
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do
    {
    System.out.print("Enter the car's model number or 0 to quit: ");
    model=input.nextInt();
    input.close();
    }   
    while (model>0);
    {

        if (model==119)
            {
                System.out.print("Your car is defective. It must be repaired.");
            }
       else if (model==179)
            {
                System.out.print("Your car is defective. It must be repaired.");
            }   
       else if (model>=189 && model<=195)
            {
                System.out.print("Your car is defective. It must be repaired.");
            }   
       else if (model==221)
            {
                System.out.print("Your car is defective. It must be repaired.");
            }
       else if (model==780)
            {
                System.out.print("Your car is defective. It must be repaired.");
            }     
       else 
             System.out.print("Your car is not defective.");
       model=0; 
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Why do you need a loop there? If you have to make just one comparison against the model number, you can just rid of the `while` loop altogether. Is there a specific reason to use the loop?

Comment: You have some messed up braces, like the one right after `import java.util.Scanner` should be removed, the while loop needs a starting brace, fix those issues,

Comment: Think about how to replace if-else with more effective construct.

Comment: yes @Rakesh, the user would be able to ask as many times as they want until they type zero

Comment: Going with the way you have coded, the loop isn't entered if the `model` value is less than or equal to `0`, and hence there is no way that `if (model == 0)` executed. If you continually want to take `model` values and process it indefinitely until a `0` is entered, you will have to move the `model=input.nextInt()` within the looping construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a while loop, which doesn't look necessary in this case change `Model` to be 0 or add a `break`

```
while(Model>0){//add the brace
   //...current if else code
   Model = 0;//or simply break;
}
```

--EDIT--  (using do while)

```
int Model; //model number
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

do{
  System.out.print("Enter the car's model number or 0 to quit: ");
  Model=input.nextInt();

  if (Model==119||Model==179||(Model>=189 && Model<=195)||Model==221||Model==780)
      System.out.println("Your car is defective. It must be repaired.");
  else if(Model>0)
      System.out.println("Your car is not defective.");
}while(Model>0);
input.close();
```

Comment: Okay, it worked, but i need it to display multiple times in one sitting. So after the "Enter the car's model number or 0 to quit: ", and the message, the program will repeat it self util you type 0

Comment: Then add `System.out.print("Enter the car's model number or 0 to quit: ");Model=input.nextInt();` right inside the loop, then might want to change into a do while loop

Comment: I did test this code, and it works so the syntax and logic is fine

Answer (score 0):

First of, there doesn't appear to be any reason you should use a loop. `model` is a number, you can do checks on it, but that isn't going to change the value of the variable `model`. So I would suggest removing the whole loop.

If you want to do something with the loop, like adjust the variable `model` at some point (but haven't implemented that yet), you can use the `break` keyword to escape the loop you are currently residing in:

```
while(model > 0){
    if (some condition to finish looping){
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to something like below

```
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter the car's model number or 0 to quit: ");
            model=input.nextInt();
            if (model == 0) {
                break; // This will break you out of the loop
            } else if (model == 119) {
                System.out.print("Your car is defective. It must be repaired.");
            } else if (model == 179) {
                System.out.print("Your car is defective. It must be repaired.");
            } else if (model >= 189 && model <= 195) {
                System.out.print("Your car is defective. It must be repaired.");
            } else if (model == 221) {
                System.out.print("Your car is defective. It must be repaired.");
            } else if (model == 780) {
                System.out.print("Your car is defective. It must be repaired.");
            } else
                System.out.print("Your car is not defective.");

        }
        // Move the scanner close to outside the loop to avoid `IllegalStateException`.
        input.close();
```

This will prompt the user to enter a new number in every iteration. When the user enters 0, it will go to the corresponding `if` condition and `break` the loop. Hope this helps.

To make the loop run forever, I changed the `while(model > 0)` to `while(true)`. This will loop to infinity until you enter a '0'.

Note: I haven't compiled this code. Just took the excerpt from what you have given the question. Also, I took the liberty to change the variable name from `Model` to `model`. It is a good practice to have variable names begin from a lower case alphabet.